# jQuery form data to div

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I'm working on a page where a form's information must be added to a div once a button is clicked.

**HTML**

```
<form id="ajout_checkboxForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="formulaireCheckbox">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>Option</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="new_checkbox[]" disabled="disabled" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="new_checkboxName[]" /></td>
                    <td><input type="button" value="Add Row" onClick="ajouterCheckbox(this.form);" /></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
            
    <p><input type="button" id="new_checkboxForm" value="<?=AJOUTER_FORMULAIRE;?>"></p>
</form>

<div id="formulaire_appercu">
    <!-- data from form comes here -->
</div>
```

**AJAX**

```
var rowNum = 0;
function ajouterCheckbox(frm)
{
    rowNum++;
    var row = '<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="new_checkbox[]" disabled="disabled" /></td><td><input type="text" name="new_checkboxName[]" /></td><td><input onClick="addRow(this.form);" type="button" value="<?=AJOUTER;?>" /></td></tr>';
    $('#formulaireCheckbox tbody').append(row);frm.add_qty.value='';frm.add_name.value='';
}

$('#new_checkboxForm').click(function(){
    /*+----------------------------------------------------+
      + This is where the problem is                       +
      + --> I am having trouble getting the information    +
      +     to show in #formulaire_appercu in a way        +
      +     where I can actually do something with it      +
      +----------------------------------------------------+*/
   
    var update = function() {
        $('#formulaire_appercu').text(
            JSON.stringify($('#ajout_checkboxForm').serialize())
        );
    };
    update();
    $('#ajout_checkboxForm').change(update);

    /*+----------------------------------------------------+
      + This is where the problem ends                     +
      +----------------------------------------------------+*/

    // cacher popup + fade
    $('.popup_block').hide();
    $('#fade').hide();
});
```

At this point, pressing on the `#new_checkboxForm` button returns this string in my div:

```
"new_checkboxName%5B%5D=test1&new_checkboxName%5B%5D=test2"
```

I'm of course understanding that `%5B%5D` represents the `[]` (perhaps this should be corrected, too, I'm guessing?).

Here's the basic structure I'm looking for:

```
<p>new_checkboxName[] = test1</p> <!-- could also be new_checkboxName[0] -->
<p>new_checkboxName[] = test2</p> <!-- could also be new_checkboxName[1] -->
```

I guess what I'm looking for is something similar to [PHP's preg_split](https://www.php.net/preg_split) in order to get to something elegant to show.

Comment: It would be very useful if you could put together a jsFiddle of what you have working so far.

Comment: Why not simply iterate the inputs of the form and get the `val()`s? It seems a very long way around to serialise and stringify it then decode and disassemble it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using `serializeArray` instead and then just format returned array:

```
var update = function () {
    var html = $.map($('#ajout_checkboxForm').serializeArray(), function(el) {
        return '<p>' + el.name + ' = ' + el.value + '</p>'; 
    }).join('');
    $('#formulaire_appercu').html(html);
};
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rj9nW/

Answer (score 0):

The serialized data is encoded so as to be URI-safe.  You can do this:

```
var decoded = decodeURIComponent(serializedText)
```

Which will give you:

```
"new_checkboxName[]=test1&new_checkboxName[]=test2"
```

From there, you can easily split and display them like so:

```
$.every(decoded.split('&'), function(index, el) {
    $('#formulaire_appercu').append('<p>' + el + '</p>);
});
```